# Java & Matlab Exception

Tags: java, matlab

```
package matlab;

import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
import com.eigenface.Eigenface;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Eigenface core = null;

        Object [] result = null;




        try {

            core = new Eigenface();
            result = core.EigenFace(2);
            System.out.println(result[0]);



        } catch (MWException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

I'm using a Matlab function in a wrapper class, called Eigenface. When I run my code i get this exception: {??? Error using ==> EigenFace
Too many output arguments.
} .
Since the function works with no problem in Matalab, does anyone knows why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this call in your code is not correct:

```
result = core.EigenFace(2);
```

Is the name of your MATLAB function `EigenFace`? If not, you should be calling something like:

```
result = core.yourfunction(2);
```

You can see the example [getmagic.java](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/javabuilder/ug/bsl9gar.html#bsl9gl2) in MATLAB documentation:

```
/* Create new magic object */
theMagic = new magic();

/* Compute magic square and print result */
result = theMagic.makesqr(1, n);
System.out.println(result[0]);
```

Comment: yes, the sintax is correct. I also tried the example you suggested and I'm getting the same exception, so I guess it's something else than the code...